# how to print only a part of a webpage in php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to print a part of a page with a single button click without opening a different page . The part of the page that i need to print has been called using ajax 
so if anybody could help me i would be really thankful

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS media print to control how your page is printed and then just use window.print().  No need to call another page.  You can hide parts of your page this way (side menus and so forth).

Comment: thank you cletus , what i really want to do is that , i have a page which shows some content but when i press the print button a completely different page should be printed , could you help me with this ?... and thanks again for replying my question... ;)